# How to track all android version in new flurry?

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

In classic flurry, we can see the all android versions by Technical>All Firmware Version. But now classic flurry is retired already.
In new flurry version, I can't find the place to see the all android version which are currently using my app. I can only see the top 10 OS version. Could you please suggest me about where can I see the all android version? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Add a flurry event which will contains o.s. version. And make sure this event will fire only once after your app installation.

Comment: did they really remove the ability to see the app version in the redesign? looks like i'm switching to google analytics.